# create a string builder in a new class

Tags: c#, winforms, stringbuilder

I want to create a string builder in a new class in c# because I have many strings(more than 7,000) to replace with. doing in same form may get loading problem so I thought of creating a new class where i can write the string builder codes but couldnt do it. I have try on below codes

```
class v
    {
        StringBuilder _sb = new StringBuilder();

        public v(StringBuilder sb)
        {
            sb.Replace("s", "A");
            sb.Replace("hi", "hello");
        }
    }
```

my button code:

```
StringBuilder _sb = new StringBuilder(c1Editor1.Text);
_sb.v(C1Editor.text);
```

Comment: Moving the `StringBuilder` to another class and using it like you attempt in the second code snippet won't do any good for performance. You will have to move the heavy lifting to another thread e.g. by using a background worker. All that said, can you elaborate a little more on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Venerik, I want to use a string builder in a new class

Answer (score 2):

```
class v
{
    StringBuilder _sb;

    public v(StringBuilder sb)
    {
        _sb = sb;
        sb.Replace("s", "A");
        sb.Replace("hi", "hello");
    }
}
```

And then:

```
StringBuilder _sb = new StringBuilder(c1Editor1.Text);
v _v = new v(_sb);
```

Not that I necessarily think that that's good code but that will achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: After look at your code, I understood the problem of op ! +1 from me :)

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what OP wants, but should the constructor be replacing text on `_sb` rather than `sb`, or does `_sb=sb` make a reference rather than a deep copy anyway?

Comment: @Namfuak, `StringBuilder` is a class, therefore a reference type, therefore there is only one `StringBuilder`.

Comment: when ever i click on Button "s" should replaced by "A" and "hi" replaced by "hello" using string builder concept in a new class but above codes are not working.

Comment: If you're expecting to see the change in the editor control then of course it's not working.  You need to put the modified text back into the control after it's done.

Comment: @ jmcilhinney Yeah I am expecting to see the changes whenever i click on Button in the Editor. Can you please share me your full codes if you dont mind it ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want change your own stringbuiler's text, how about this one?

1.Create StringBuilder Handler

```
public static class StringHelper
{
    public static void v(this StringBuilder  sb)
    {
        sb.Replace("s", "A");
        sb.Replace("hi", "hello");
    }
}
```

2.User handler class in your code

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(c1Editor1.Text);
sb.v();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it. Paste the code in a form with a `TextBox` called `textBox1`, a `Button` called `button1` and a `BackgroundWorker` called `backgroundWorker1`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // instead of changing the cursor you could disable the textbox
    this.UseWaitCursor = true;
    backgroundWorker1.DoWork += Replacer;
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(textBox1.Text);
}

private void Replacer(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
{
    var replacer = new StringBuilder((String)doWorkEventArgs.Argument);
    replacer.Replace("s", "A");
    replacer.Replace("hi", "hello");
    // add other 6998 replacements here and remove the sleep of course
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    doWorkEventArgs.Result = replacer.ToString();
}

void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = (string) e.Result;
    // instead of changing the cursor you could enable the textbox here
    this.UseWaitCursor = false;
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @ Venerik, but i think i have gave you wrong elaboration because what i need to do is when ever i click on Button all "s" should replaced by "A" using stringBuilder.replace("s","A"); and so on .. and this implementation code should happen in a new class(Let say V.cs). So your help are meant me lots.

Comment: I am able to see the replacement arein messagebox form by using below codes: //code for v.cs                                              class v{ private StringBuilder _sb;
        public v(StringBuilder _sb1){this._sb = _sb1; _sb.Replace("s", "A");_sb.Replace("hi", "hello"); MessageBox.Show("Text hasbeen changed" + _sb)}                                                                                     //code for button:StringBuilder _sb1 = new StringBuilder(c1Editor1.Text);v _sb = new v(_sb1);} but I want see the text changes in Editor itself say C1Editor1. Your helps are most appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to create a new class. It doesn't make sense unless you are trying to achieve something you haven't mentioned yet.